# IE 11 error - Access is denied - XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest, internet-explorer-11

I'm having a peculiar error with IE11 and ajax. For nearly all the requests I make using the code below, everything is fine, yet when I try use in conjunction with a copy+paste method, it returns an Access is denied error. So to summarise

- This code works normally in most browsers for all functions I have written
- In IE 11 + Windows 8.1, it works in most cases, except when running a particular copy and paste function
- Interestingly, when using IE 11, but with a different Document mode such as 8, I still get the same error, even though it works natively in IE8 + Windows 7
- The error is 'Access is denied'

Here is the AJAX code:

```
function ajaxRequest(requestName,responseFunction,parameters) {
 var xmlhttp;
 if (requestName.length==0) return;
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest)  {
     xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 } else {
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
     if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
        if(xmlhttp.responseText == 'Error') alert('Error processing request. Please refresh the page and try again');
        else if(xmlhttp.responseText != '') eval(responseFunction+"('"+xmlhttp.responseText+"')");
     }
 }
 var now = new Date();
 var url = "control/ajax.php?request="+requestName+"&parameters="+parameters+"&timestamp"+now;
 xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
 xmlhttp.send();
}
```

An example of a failure, had the following variables set:

requestName: "save_marksheet_mark"
responseFunction: "update_save_marksheet_mark"
parameters: [60962,1284,5]

Is there something wrong with this code? Is there a reason why IE11 would throw an error with this code, in particular circumstances?

Comment: Refer this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22098259/access-denied-in-ie-10-and-11-when-ajax-target-is-localhost

Comment: This isn't a cross domain request - 
    var url = "control/ajax.php...
It's requesting a page on the same site as the user is already visiting

Comment: *"yet when I try use in conjunction with a copy+paste method, it returns an Access is denied error"* did you try the copy paste on it's own to see if that's where the "Access Denied" error is originating from? eliminate unnecessary code if possible.

Comment: That was my initial thought, but the error is clearly on the xmlhttp.open line (as highlighted in the developer tools) - when I comment that out (as well as xmlhttp.send), there are no errors.

Comment: Try putting the `xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true)` line above the `xmlhttp.onreadstatchange` declaration.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion ibdehold, but that didn't seem to work. The crazy thing is I can get the function to work with exactly the same data, but just when called by a different function - the one that works just saves a single cell, the one that doesn't reads the clipboard and then saves on cell at a time. So strange!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This question appears to be getting a lot of views, so just in case anybody was wondering, I solved this problem by using a setTimeout() on the original AJAX call. E.g:

```
setTimeout(function() {
        ajaxRequest('save_mark','save_mark_completed',[60962,1284,5]) 
    }, 1);
```

I'm assuming it's some kind of bug in IE. Just 1 millisecond was all it needed!

Comment: This is so ridiculous and I am very grateful to you for posting this explanation because I would have struggled with it for a long time before figuring out what on earth was going on.

Comment: How does a 1ms timeout fix the issue?  This makes the request succeed?

Comment: I can't tell you why it works, but it definitely does! I guess it's just a bug!

Answer (score -1):

```
setTimeout(function() {
        ajaxRequest('save_mark','save_mark_completed',[60962,1284,5]) 
    }, 1);
```

This did work for me for the first call after page load but later calls again started to show Access is denied error