# Read local file using XMLHttpRequest in IE

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer

I am using following code to read local file.

```
request = new (window.ActiveXObject || XMLHttpRequest)("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
request.open("GET", url, 0);
request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.send();
document.write(request.responseText);
return request.responseText;
```

But it will not work in IE.It throws an error '**Access Denied**'.Is there any other way to read local file using java script?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access denied in IE 10 and 11 when ajax target is localhost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22098259/access-denied-in-ie-10-and-11-when-ajax-target-is-localhost)

Comment: with `local ` you mean `inside user's PC` or `inside the same webserver/localhost`?

Comment: From hard disk not from webserver or localhost

Comment: It's impossible because it's security hole. BTW, this was blocked in IE5.5. ;)

Comment: @Ginden You meant, it's "by design" ;)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any other way to read local file using java script?

No, unless explicitly allowed by user using `<input type="file">`. Then it can be processed using [HTML5 File APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications)

I can recommend you [quite good tutorial on File API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/).