# PDF.js HTA, promise being rejected

Tags: javascript, hta, pdf.js

I'm trying to develop an HTA for extracting and processing the data from PDF files for a number of people in a large office.  I've been looking into using the [PDF.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) package for this, but I've not been able to get it working.

I've [forked the project](https://github.com/xarxziux/pdf.js/tree/hta) and created an HTA version of the helloworld example with the compatibility.js file included. I can get an HTML version of this working on Firefox and IE11 through a gulp server, but the HTA doesn't give any output - no text, no error messages.

After peppering the source files with alert() statements, I've discovered that the original hello.js file is missing promise reject function, and that this fires when added, but here where my I meet the limits of my knowledge.  I don't really know an awful lot about promises, so I don't understand why this one fails.  Is this solvable or does it mean that the package simply won't run in an HTA?

---

EDIT:

I've been looking more into this and the failure doesn't make sense.

Tracing the logic through, the hello.js file calls the function api.getDocument from api.js.  Following this back, there is only one return statement and the alert statement just before this line is running. However the fulfilled function is not triggering.

From my very limited understanding, the failure clause on a promise will be triggered from a throw() statement within the asynchronous operation.  If that is the case then I would expect that operation to immediately cease and the reject function to trigger,  but why would the line immediately before the return statement still run?

I did pursue one theory that this line from api.js was the one throwing the error:

```
}).catch(task._capability.reject);
```

To check this, I added an alert statement to the reject() function statement in util.js, but it did not trigger, so I can't tell where the error is coming from.

Is anyone able to give me any additional pointers to help me trace this down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

By changing the compatibility setting to IE10 instead of IE9 (which I didn't know I could do) I got a more useful error in the right place.  Looking more into this, this issue appears to be a duplicate of this one:

[Access denied in IE 10 and 11 when ajax target is localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22098259/access-denied-in-ie-10-and-11-when-ajax-target-is-localhost)